# Open a sheet from VBA Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have 199 supplier names in my datasheet. Every one of them has a spreadsheet for themselves.
As you can guess I need to find the necessary spreadsheet manually by clicking. So how could I automate the process with VBA via Combobox?

Comment: Right-click the two little arrows to the left of the tab names.  This will bring up the [Activate](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/activate-sheet-8a4e2455-2547-4d4c-8347-82a4a68a99f3?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=21185&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) box listing all sheets for you to select.  They're ordered the same as the tab order rather than alphabetically though.

Comment: Thanks for your so clear help. 
Could I do that with VBA codes an Combobox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everyone.

I figure it out with Listbox.

```
Private Sub TextBox17_Change()

Dim i As Long
Me.TextBox17.Text = StrConv(Me.TextBox17.Text, 1)
Me.ListBox4.Clear
For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sayfa1.Range("A:A"))
a = Len(Me.TextBox17.Text)
'If Left(Sayfa2.Cells(i, 3).Value, a) = Left(Me.TextBox17.Text, a) Then
If Sayfa1.Cells(i, 1).Value Like "*" & TextBox17.Text & "*" Then
Me.ListBox4.AddItem Sayfa1.Cells(i, 1).Value
Me.ListBox4.List(ListBox4.ListCount - 1, 3) = Sayfa1.Cells(i, 1).Value
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub ListBox4_Click()

    Dim x As Variant
        x = ListBox4.Text
        Sheets(x).Select
    Unload Me

End Sub
```